# Circle tangent to line and twin circle

Tags: geometry

I really need to found a specific solution for this specific issue.

**I have a:** radius (fillet between 2 lines) with R80mm (blue color) circle tangent to this fillet with diameter 35mm (blue color)

**What I need:** I need to calculate the *pink circle*, that also has diameter 35mm. This new circle must be tangent to line (pink) and inner circle (blue)

Beside know the diameter of blue circle, I also can know the center angle or XY center coordinates.

[image: Graphic]

Please let me know

Thanks on advance

Pedro

Answer (score 3):

The center of the pink circle is at the intersection of a vertical at distance $r$ ($35/2$ mm) of the pink line, and a circle of radius $2r$ concentric with the blue circle.

To find this intersection numerically, solve

$$(x-x_c)^2+(y-y_c)^2=4r^2,\\x=x_v+r,$$ which is trivial.

[image]

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words ... therfore ... Your solution is better than mine

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit: mh, I added text as well ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Draw a line parallel to the pink line that is at a distance of 17.5 from it & on the right hand side. Now set your compass to 35 and place the center at the center of the small blue circle & mark off where it intersects the line; This will give you the center of the pink circle.

To construct the center of the green circle ... set your compass to 80-17.5=62.5 & place the center at the cross & draw this circle. Now do the same as last time ...set your compass to 35 and place the center at the center of the small blue circle & mark off where it intersects the circle (you have just drawn); This will give you the center of the green circle.

I have assumed that the radii of the pink & green circles are 35.